# Mock dependencies with Mocha and Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

I have a typescript project which uses mocha. Let's say we have two modules as follows.

```
// http.ts
export class Http {
}

// app.ts
import Http from './http';

export class App {

}
```

How could I **mock the Http module when I'm testing the App?**

The test is executed through the npm script as below.

```
"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha",
```

And the mocha options (mocha.opts) looks like below.

```
test/setup.ts
--compilers ts:ts-node/register
--compilers tsx:ts-node/register
./src/**/*.spec.ts
```

Answer (score 6):

[ts-mock-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mock-imports) gives you run time control over your imports and maintains type safety.

in `app.spec.ts`

```
import * as httpModule from 'http';
import { App } from '../src/app';
import { ImportMock } from 'ts-mock-imports';

const httpMock = ImportMock.mockClass(httpModule, 'Http');

const app = new App(); // App now uses a fake version of the Http class
```

Now you can control how the Http module behaves in your tests.

Mock the response to a get:

```
httpMock.mock('get', { data: true });

const response = app.makeGetRequest(); // returns { data: true }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `import` statement in typescript is compiled to `require`. You can use [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to mock any dependencies in your tests

Comment: I could not get it work with proxyquire either. I ended up using webpack with inject-loader.

Comment: @Raathigesh would you mind sharing your findings? I am trying to achieve the same thing..

Comment: @AndyPerlitch I ended up using webpack and Inject-loader (https://github.com/plasticine/inject-loader)

Comment: Spent hours trying to get `inject-loader` to work. Perhaps this will benefit others to know that the latest inject-loader version (3.0.0-beta2 as of this writing) failed. I had to downgrade to 2.0.1

Comment: @AndyPerlitch Did you try proxyquire?

Comment: @BillyTom I did try to set up proxyquire but couldn't get it to work. Have you used proxyquire successfully in a typescript+webpack environment?

Comment: @AndyPerlitch No, I have only used it in pure JavaScript tests.

Comment: I created [ts-mock-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mock-imports) to work like proxyquire in typescript environments.

Comment: Looking back at my answer I would do it differently today. In the long run it is easier to use something like [Inversify](http://inversify.io/) to inject mock dependencies into your tests.